# HttpURLConnection Instantiation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, forceclose

When I instantiate my HTTPURLConnection, it works fine in the debugger, but the app force closes on my phone. I need to find out what is wrong with it because it is pretty similar to the sample code and I'm fairly sure that it's correct. Are there any other suggestions for things to do. I'm basically trying to read a JSONArray from the website as of now. I also have the two required permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

package com.example.abhilaash.reader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String WIFI = "Wi-Fi";
    public static final String ANY = "Any";
    private static final String myurl = "http://www.antarice.com/concepts/vnotam/document.json";
    public static String sPref = null;
    private static boolean wifiConnected = false;
    private static boolean mobileConnected = false;
    public static boolean refreshDisplay = true;
    private JSONArray json = null;
    private ListView listview = null;
    private TextView textview = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        updateConnectedFlags();
        if (refreshDisplay) {
            loadPage();
        }
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int x = 0; x < json.length(); x++) {
            try {
                al.add(json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamnumber") + "\n" + json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamtext"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, al);
        listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int x = 0; x < json.length(); x++) {
            try {
                al.add(json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamnumber") + "\n" + json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamtext"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, al);
        listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregisters BroadcastReceiver when app is destroyed.
        if (receiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    }


    public void loadPage() {
        if (((sPref.equals(ANY)) && (wifiConnected || mobileConnected))
                || ((sPref.equals(WIFI)) && (wifiConnected))) {
            // AsyncTask subclass
            new download().execute(myurl);
        } else {
            showErrorPage();
        }
    }

    public void showErrorPage() {
        textview.setText("ERROR");
    }

    private void updateConnectedFlags() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // Retrieves a string value for the preferences. The second parameter
        // is the default value to use if a preference value is not found.
        sPref = sharedPrefs.getString("listPref", "Wi-Fi");
        NetworkInfo activeInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeInfo != null && activeInfo.isConnected()) {
            wifiConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
            mobileConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
        } else {
            wifiConnected = false;
            mobileConnected = false;
        }
    }

    private class download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return loadFromNetwork(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                json = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        String str = "";
        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            str = readIt(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    /**
     * Given a string representation of a URL, sets up a connection and gets
     * an input stream.
     *
     * @param urlString A string representation of a URL.
     * @return An InputStream retrieved from a successful HttpURLConnection.
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Start the query
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }


    protected String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        String a = "";
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        if (reader.ready()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                a += line;
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
        }
        return a;
    }
```

This is the logcat

```
08-08 15:22:36.471  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT    chunk
08-08 15:22:36.471  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.abhilaash.reader is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-08 15:22:36.481  20559-20565/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
08-08 15:22:36.671  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
08-08 15:22:36.671  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:36.871  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:37.071  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:37.271  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:37.471  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:37.671  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:37.871  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-08 15:22:38.071  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1346)
08-08 15:22:38.201  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-08 15:22:39.391  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-08 15:22:46.281  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-08 15:22:46.361  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 270
08-08 15:22:46.461  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
08-08 15:22:46.501  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 271
08-08 15:22:46.521  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 272
08-08 15:22:46.521  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-08 15:22:46.581  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:12 height:12 bitmap id is 273
08-08 15:22:46.591  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-08 15:22:46.631  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 274
08-08 15:22:49.441  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-08 15:22:50.901  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b63da0)
08-08 15:22:59.531  20559-20559/com.example.abhilaash.reader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.abhilaash.reader, PID: 20559
    android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.abhilaash.reader/com.example.abhilaash.reader.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onStart()
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5463)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post LogCat error? You should see there a reason or at least a hint about what is going on.

Comment: just to discard possibilities, could you try to call the method **downloadUrl** outside an AsyncTask class? if it works, for sure your problem is during the background process, not in the http connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this code didn't work was because the JSONArray didn't get instantiated in the ASYNC Task fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

the method **loadPage()** executes asynchronously, therefore you can't just expect that the output is immediately available on the next line like you did...so the 'json' is null right after you call it..on can only expect these variables to be available after the **onPostExecute()** gets called.

So what you have to do is put the code that processes the JSON result in a method out of the **onStart()** and call this new method from the **onPostExecute()**.

Comment: So I tried doing that and I made a method: 
private void displayJSON(){ 
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int x = 0; x < json.length(); x++) { 
try { al.add(json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamnumber") + "\n" + json.getJSONObject(x).getString("notamtext")); } 
catch (JSONException e) {.printStackTrace();             }         }
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, al);         listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);     } 
but it doesn't work.